# My homepage product slider is only showing one item

Tags: phtml

I'm using the below code (in new.phtml) to show a 4 column slider on my homepage for my products.

It's currently only showing one product, any ideas how to make it show 8 products?

Thanks!

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.cycle.all.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#banners').cycle({
            fx:'scrollHorz',
            width: 1024,
            height: 380,
            prev: '#prev',
            next: '#next',
            timeout: 800000
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="box-top"></div>
<h2 class="subtitle label"><?php echo $this->__('Our exclusive trade range of synthetic grass') ?></h2>

<div class="new-products-slider">
    <a id="next">next</a>
    <a id="prev">prev</a>
    <div id="banners">
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
                <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
                <div class="data">
                    <ul class="products-grid" id="afayc">
                        <?php endif ?>
                            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(203) ?>" width="203" height="203" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                                <h3 class="product-name height-li">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                                        <?php $small_getName = strip_tags($this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()));
                                         if (strlen($small_getName) < 40) echo($small_getName);
                                         else {
                                          echo substr($small_getName, 0, 40);
                                          echo '...';
                                          } ?>
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="desc std">
                                    <?php echo $_product->getShortDescription() ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-bottom height-li-2">
                                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="actions">
                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Details') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></span></span></button>
                                    <!-- <?php // if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <button type="button" title="<?php // echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php // echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php // echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                    <?php // else: ?>
                                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php // echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                                    <?php // endif; ?>
                                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                                        <?php // if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                            <li><a title="<?php // echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php //  echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist tooltips"><?php // echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                        <?php // endif; ?>
                                        <?php // if ($_compareUrl = $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php // echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php // echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>" class="link-compare tooltips"><?php // echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                        <?php //  endif; ?>
                                    </ul>-->
                                    <!-- <div class="list-reviews"> <?php // echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?> </div>-->
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <?php // echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-bottom"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setHeight('.height-li');
        setHeight('.height-li-2');
    });
</script><!--yeps-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

```
...
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
...
```

use this: `<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products as $_product): ?>`

hope this helps

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, still just showing one product on the page.

Comment: Also look to this row <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?> . I dont understand this, because if $_columnCount equal 4, then  product will be display when $i = 4 or $i = 8. Try to comment out this condition.